# How to get the selected text?

Tags: html, dart, dart-html

<s>In Chrome,</s> I can use

```
window.getSelection().toString()
```

to get the selected text. However, <s>even though Mozilla Developer Network [says it should work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/toString), in Firefox,</s> this doesn't give the selected text but rather the literal string `Instance of 'Selection'`.

<s>What's the correct way to get the selected text?</s>

Comment: Seems it's overridden by Darts default `toString()` implementation. What about `window.getSelection().getRangAt(0)`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Should have mentioned I tried that as well, similar result.

Comment: What does "similar result" mean exactly?

Comment: `Instance of 'xG'`. Actually, now that you mentioned it's probably a bug in Dart (I hadn't thought about that), I tried it in regular Chrome rather than Dartium and the same happens as in Firefox. So it looks like this is a Dart2JS bug after all... I'll look at the output Javascript code tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This looks definitely like a bug in `dart:html`.

As workaround you can use js-interop

[**DartPad example**](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/c25b2eeca406ced1a3d3c3580cf8693b)

```
import 'dart:js';
...
print(context.callMethod('getSelection'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Dart2JS was indeed the culprit. Turning minification off and looking at the output Javascript reveals:

```
t2 = J.getInterceptor(selection);
t1 = t2.toString$0(selection);
```

Manually replacing it after compiling with:

```
t1 = selection.toString();
```

fixes the issue.

I've reported the bug: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/27789